# How to rewrite a particular block of file

Tags: c, unix

I want to rewrite a particular block in a file but its not working for me

For example if I want to rewrite to offset 4 of the file I used lseek(fd,4,SEEK_SET) and called write system call but its writing at the end of the file instead of at offset 4.

Comment: Post your code.  That should work fine.  You didn't use `O_APPEND`, did you?

Comment: @matthew I used open("file.txt",O_RDWR |O_CREAT|O_APPEND,0644);

Comment: Are you the same mousey: http://stackoverflow.com/users/329326/mousey ?

Comment: yeah but I lost that account :(

Comment: You can flag this question for the mods and ask them to merge your accounts.

Comment: @Moron how to do it ? Just email them ?

Comment: Do you see a 'flag' link anywhere on this page? Try clicking that and see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `O_APPEND`.  It will append everything to the end of the file, regardless of your seeking.

Use:

```
open("file.txt", O_RDWR);
```

You're assuming the file already exists, so I don't see why you would use `O_CREAT`.

Comment: thank you very much. If I want to restart a file how to do it ?

Comment: You mean truncate it?  You can use [`ftruncate`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ftruncate.html).

Comment: yeah thats what I wanted. Also can I remove some data in between two offsets ?